# using s3cmd with a different, s3 like, provider

Tags: python, configuration, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd), a python command line tool, with a S3-like provider different from AWS. When I set up the whole system I clearly remember that I search for the endpoint and change the default AWS one with the one I'm using (so endpoint was not a config option), then complete the configuration process and right now I'm still working with s3cmd.

Anyway recently I had to setup s3cmd on another machine and, not remembering where to set the endpoint, I grep the address of the provider on my machine, but without finding any result.
Do you have any suggestion on where can it be?

edit:
Ok, apparently there's a .s3cfg stored in the home directory and that's where the endpoint is. I still can't understand from where the value come from though

Answer (score 5):

In this config file you should have 2 lines like this :

```
host_base = s3.amazonaws.com  
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.s3.amazonaws.com
```

You can then change it to point at your ViPR instance:

```
host_base = s3.mydomain.com 
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.s3.mydomain.com
```

Note: Your ViPR solution has to support aws virtual naming style. Otherwhise, you have to use pathstyle.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly set configuration file, use `-c` option, as:

```
s3cmd ls --recursive --list-md5 s3://bucket-name -c ~/.s3cfg-profile-2
```

That way, you are assured that you are reading the configs that are stored into file `~/.s3cfg-profile-2`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
s3cmd --configure
```

Follow it through and it will prompt you for the endpoint URL and the bucket URL, instead of having to fill out the config file for yourself.